# Safari / Chrome flex-parent 100% height + padding and 100% height child

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

Safari makes `child` block's height larger than Chrome.

I need to implement the block behaviour same in Chrome and in Safari.

Padding in Chrome affects on `child's height`. Padding in Safari sums with `height`.

```
.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ctn {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.ctn__child {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zqjpzLLb/

Comment: Have you tried adding `box-sizing: border-box`? https://jsfiddle.net/zqjpzLLb/1/

Comment: In this fiddle padding in Safari less than padding in Chrome

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Are your iframe client-heights the same while using JSFiddle? Cause these are affecting the height as well.

I've managed to get same height cross-browser using the following code:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4f4;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4a4;
}

.ctn {
  display: inherit; /* Inherit display flex for __child grow inside */
  flex-grow: 1; /* Make sure it fills up the remaining parent space */
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.ctn__child {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Let the child fill all the remaining space inside the .ctn class */
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 100, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="ctn">
    <div class="ctn__child">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zqjpzLLb/17/